# How to scroll to top of element in an overlay using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, scroll, scrollto

I have an overlay that has multiple steps that use separate Ajax calls. I'm using plain JavaScript, so no jQuery. The problem I am having is if I'm at the bottom of the scrollable DIV in Step 1, go to Step 2, then click the Edit link to go back to Step 1, it shows the location that I last viewed instead of being at the top of the scrollable area.

Can someone tell me how to fix this? I've tried window.scroll and window.scrollTo, but couldn't get either to work.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem. It will be much easier to help you ff you post some code, or even better, make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding the following line inside a method that's called each time a view is changed in the overlay.

```
div.scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: This was the clue I needed - we can scroll to the top of the element rather than the window. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery method of `.scrollTop(value)` works.

And if you want visually appealing movement to that point use [this scrollTo plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) along with the very famous easing plugin.